# How to Center an oracle form in oracle form builder?

Tags: forms, oracle, position, center, builder

can anyone tell me how to position an oracle form in the middle of the screen when maximize the window ?
Actually i have a form when i run it, it displayed at the upper left corner of the screen but i want it to be displayed in the center of the screen even while enlarge the window.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS style for make this form middle of the page.
Is that form have fixed width?
Then use this style

```
.formSelector{margin: 0 auto;}
```

I think it will be working.